# Akka: getting info about current actor hierarchy

Tags: akka, akka-supervision

For debug purposes I'd like to have a programmatic way to get tree of non-terminated actors that are currently in the system.

Anything that can give\can be converted to textual represenatation of the current state of actor hierarchy will also be sufficient.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't traverse actor hierarchy directly. However you could subscribe your every actor to [Event Bus](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/scala/event-bus.html) and then have one actor to send a Path Report message to the Event Bus and gather all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the actor hierarchy recursively but since the number of actors in a given system are usually elastic, the answer may not be reliable.